# How to draw a shape in the future on Tradingview advanced chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, shapes, tradingview-api

I want to draw in the future exactly where the transaction would be completed. But the chart only draws a figure to the end of my candles. Is it possible to draw a figure in the future and draw a line between the start of the trade and the end of the trade

The graph does not draw figures in the future

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.